# How to wait until timer is stopped in java?

Tags: java, timer, wait, sleep

I have a method, which is calling a swing timer to start, and after calling this method, i have to wait until the executed timer stops. I tried

```
while(timer.isRunning(){}
```

but it didnt worked, it just froze my program. Please help me and forgive me for my bad english.

Comment: what is timer ?

Comment: Doesn't the timer call a method when it is done ? Can't you use that ?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? If you need to wait for timer task to finish maybe you can use `CompletableFuture#supplyAsync` for that case easily. Other possibilities are `Executor` or logic inside timer to somehow broadcast the 'execution finished' event (Listener-like pattern or simple method call).

Comment: Also if `while(timer.isRunning(){}` is frozing the program it means that your're doing it on some critical (UI?) thread in which case you need some asynchronous way to handle the event of timer finish.

Comment: Yes i am using UI and the timer ends when the x key on the keboard is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the solution, I used an integer to keep track of the iteration count of my method. When the integer got bigger than a certain number, I knew the time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is very bad practice as you force your program to run a loop without any meaning. Imagine the timer will never return, in that case you created an endless loop.

Try thread.sleep(). Start the timer before sleep(). The timer will throw a InterruptedException if it has finished. Even better: if you wake up naturally, then you should decide if you want to sleep again and keep waiting for the timer or if you want to throw an error / do something else.

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Comment: @Yoshie2000 This will have the same effect as your `while` loop if you execute it on the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT).

Comment: Have a look here for more details: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTimers.htm

Comment: This didnt work for me. Is there another way maybe? I need user input in the timer, maybe that helps

Comment: You have to tell us a little bit more. Are you using one Thread for the timer and the while loop? What are you trying to achieve? All replies are based on common usages of timers so far because you just gave us one line of code. What do you mean with user input inside the timer? You use the time selected by an user to start the timer? Please give us some more code.